# Do I have to read NSOperationQueue's operationCount on the operation queue itself?

Tags: ios, nsoperationqueue

Sometimes it seems `operationCount` does not return the right value. Do I have to access it from the queue itself or it does not matter if I access it from an other thread?

Comment: I would have expected it to be thread-safe. The docs say that `operationCount` is KVO-compliant and can be accessed from any thread: `However, KVO notifications associated with an operation queue may occur in any thread.`. Link to docs (under KVO-Compliant Properties): https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/index.html . Have you tried KVO to see if that reports "better" numbers?

Comment: it is volatile though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"the value returned by this property reflects the instantaneous number of operations at the time the property was accessed."

it isn't guaranteed to be precise / stable and you should NOT use it to do calculations / decisions